# Exception: Invalid instance in App.root error in kivy

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, kivy

I got Exception: Invalid instance in App.root error when i tried to run the program. Any help would be appreciated

```
import serial
import kivy
from kivy.app import App

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        while (1):
            with serial.Serial('COM4', 9600) as ser:
                x = ser.readline()
                ser.close()
                return float(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: The `build()` method is expected to return a `Widget`, not a number.

Comment: so what function am i supposed to use to return a number?

Comment: @Budaksesat2000 What do you expect your code to do? IMHO your code does not make sense, the build method returns a widget that will be displayed in the window but you return a floating, somewhat illogical.

Comment: You can write your own method to return a number, just don't hijack a method that is already being used for something else, i.e, don't call it 'build' if it's inside an `App` class.